# Parallel variable extension output to argument inside quotes

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel, variable-expansion

I`m trying to expand a variable inside parallel for a program argument

For example
TAG=IMPACT

```
ls *vcf | parallel -k -v 'bcftools query -f "%$TAG/n"'
```

Where it should be expanded to

```
ls *vcf | parallel -k -v 'bcftools query -f "%IMPACT/n"'
```

I tried many variantions of "" and '' as I could think of, but I always get

```
bcftools query -f %IMPACT/n

bcftools query -f '"%$TAG/n"'
```

Or anything else like

```
bcftools query -f '"%"$TAG"\n"'
```

Tried some variantions of parallel like --shellquote but no combination worked out and expanded correctly (if it is possible at all)

I tried by delimiting everything inside $TAG
like:

```
TAG="%IMPACT/n"
```

then

```
ls *vcf | parallel -k -v 'bcftools query -f '"%$TAG/n"''
```

Which could work, but is there a way to expand it inside the code and not outside of it?

Just as a test that I was doing,
Using

```
 ls *vcf | parallel -k -v 'bcftools +split-vep -f '"$TAG"' {} |  tr '"$COMMA"' '"$SPACE"''
```

When defining

```
TAG='"%IMPACT/n"'
SPACE='"/n"'
COMMA='","'
```

Expands to:

```
bcftools +split-vep -f "%IMPACT/n" input.vcf |  tr "," "/n"
```

Comment: Variables aren't expanded inside  single quotes. Use `-v "bcftools query -f '%$TAG/n'"`

Comment: Why using 
 find . -type f -name "*.vcf" | parallel -k -v 'bcftools +split-vep -f '"$TAG"' {} |  tr '"$COMMA"' '"$SPACE"''

When defining 

TAG='"%IMPACT/n"'

SPACE='"/n"'
COMMA='","'

Expands to:
bcftools +split-vep -f "%IMPACT/n" input.vcf |  tr "," "/n"
In my bash?

Comment: You shouldn't put literal `"` in the value of `TAG`. and `SPACE`

Comment: Sorry, but why not?

Comment: Because I don't think you need them. Quotes are needed when writing commands, they're not usually needed in values.

Comment: But also, my variables are being expanded while inside parallel, which seems to differ from the behaviour you are saying

Comment: `'"$COMMA"'` won't expand the variable `COMMA` because it's inside single quotes.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I was confused by the way you keep starting and ending quotes in the arguments to `parallel`. It's hard to tell which shell is expanding the variables.

Comment: The paralell way of expanding shell quotes makes me confused and the behaviour (for me at least) seems a bit unpredictible. Maybe we should let others try to respond?

Answer (score 1):

Since `parallel` is being started in a subprocess make sure to `export TAG` beforehand to insure `parallel` can properly expand `$TAG` at run time:

```
$ export TAG

$ ls file?.vcf | parallel -k -v 'echo "%$TAG%"'
echo "%$TAG%" file1.vcf 
%IMPACT% file1.vcf                               # $TAG expanded at parallel call
echo "%$TAG%" file2.vcf
%IMPACT% file2.vcf
echo "%$TAG%" file3.vcf
%IMPACT% file3.vcf
```

---

Alternatively, allow `$TAG` to be expanded by the OS by wrapping the `parallel` script in double quotes:

```
$ ls file?.vcf | parallel -k -v "echo '%$TAG%'"
echo '%IMPACT%' file1.vcf                        # $TAG expanded at command line
%IMPACT% file1.vcf
echo '%IMPACT%' file2.vcf
%IMPACT% file2.vcf
echo '%IMPACT%' file3.vcf
%IMPACT% file3.vcf
```

If you need to maintain the inner double quotes then escape them:

```
$ ls file?.vcf | parallel -k -v "echo \"%$TAG%\""
echo "%IMPACT%" file1.vcf                        # $TAG expanded at command line
%IMPACT% file1.vcf
echo "%IMPACT%" file2.vcf
%IMPACT% file2.vcf
echo "%IMPACT%" file3.vcf
%IMPACT% file3.vcf
```